# Name for this axiom $(X \bullet R) \sqcup (Y \bullet S) \equiv (X \sqcup Y) \bullet (R \sqcup S)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, lattice-orders

I am trying to give a name to this axiom in a definition:

$(X \bullet R) \sqcup (Y \bullet S) \equiv (X \sqcup Y) \bullet (R \sqcup S)$

(for all $X, Y, R, S$) where $\sqcup$ is the join of a lattice and $\bullet$ is some binary operation. It feels related to monotonicity/distributivity but I don't know a standard name for this. Any ideas? So far I have called it "full distributivity". I'd also like to have a name (possibly the same) for this axiom when $\sqcup$ isn't a lattice operation, just some binary operation.

Comment: This is called *abides*.

Two operations $\oplus,\otimes$ "abide" iff for all $x,y,u,v$ we have $ (x \oplus y) \otimes (u \oplus v) = (x \otimes u) \oplus (y \otimes v)$.

The name is an abbreviation of above-beside: draw $\oplus$ as a fraction and draw $\otimes$ as a vertical bar, then the naming makes more sense.


( Originally coined by Richard Bird(?); a quick Google-search yielded http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3390/PRG69.pdf, see page 38 for the motivation. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In higher category theory, something very similar is called the interchange law, and is an axiom for a [2-category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-category) and similar structures. It's also one of the preconditions for the [Eckmann-Hilton argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument), where I've also occasionally seen it called the interchange property.

Answer (score 2):

Of course this makes sense for arbitrary two binary operation. It says that $\sqcup$ and $\bullet$ *[commute](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+algebraic+theory)* with each other. Equivalently, $\bullet$ is a $\sqcup$-homomorphism (and by symmetry, also $\sqcup$ is a $\bullet$-homomorphism).